# Scala, Sublime Text 3 - Stop closing curly brace from jumping when followed by text

Tags: scala, sublimetext3

Whenever I am typing a multi-block code construct in Scala (e.g. `if..else..`, `for..yield..`) if I write text after the first closing curly brace without first filling out the body, Sublime "helpfully" indents the curly brace.  This also happens when I write multiple closing brackets / braces / parentheses in the same line.  Examples:

```
if (condition) {

  } else {

  }

for {

  } yield {

  }

list.map(x => {

  })
```

How can I force the closing curly brace to stay put?

Comment: My god, thank you for asking this question.

Comment: You're so welcome - the frustration had built to a point where it really needed to be asked.  But @m-z really gets the credit for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel your pain here, but I've somehow just put up with this behavior for years. Until now, of course. I scoured through the user and language preferences, ripping things out until there was nothing left. That's when I realized it wasn't what was in the preferences or language file that was causing the problem, but what *wasn't* there. Since many other languages have the same if/else syntax, I tried many of those if/else statements with them. C, C++, and Java didn't have this problem, but C# did. What was missing? **Indentation rules.**

I just copied the indentation rules from the Java package, because it's very similar in syntax, and changed the extensions to scala. I'm working on linux, so I'm not sure what the exact path should be on other operating systems, but I imagine it will be similar after `${HOME}`.

**${HOME}/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Scala/Indentation Rules.tmPreferences**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Indentation Rules</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.scala - comment</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>decreaseIndentPattern</key>
        <string>^(.*\*/)?\s*\}.*$|^\s*(public|private|protected):\s*$</string>
        <key>increaseIndentPattern</key>
        <string>^.*\{[^}"']*$|^\s*(public|private|protected):\s*$</string>

        <key>bracketIndentNextLinePattern</key>
        <string>(?x)
        ^ \s* \b(if|while|else)\b [^;]* $
        | ^ \s* \b(for)\b .* $
        </string>

    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>20E93106-18CF-4BA3-9DA3-8F0C955DB774</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

(Or `your-subl-config-folder-here../Packages/Scala/Indentation Rules.tmPreferences` if your config is saved elsewhere. The structure of the `Packages` directory should be the same.)

You will most likely have to create the `Scala` directory within your sublime `Packages` directory. For Sublime Text 2, the solution is exactly the same, except the Scala directory with all the language files is already there. I've tried it out with all the syntax I can think  of, and nothing seems wrong yet. It's possible that this might need a few adjustments, though.